# HTTP server using BSD sockets not closing connection or communicating with Windows browser

Tags: c++, c, sockets, http, unix

I'm attempting to use a simple HTTP server written in C that makes use of UNIX BSD sockets. I've got it working somewhat but am having the following issues.

1. The server only prints "hello world!" on Linux browsers and not on windows browsers; i.e., I can make use of Chrome / Firefox on Linux and see the text in the browser, but not on a Windows machine in the same browsers.
2. Rather then sending "hello world" with all of the response headers and closing the connection like a normal web page, what I'm seeing is that when I test the server page (localhost:xxxx) I am presented with the text and HTTP responses in the code but the page is in a continuous load (tab keeps spinning). Then the moment I turn the server off the page returns "failed to connect to server".

My question is, given the below code, why does this not display out to browsers on Windows and why does it not close the connection whilst leaving the client with the information sent?

This uses simple BSD sockets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  //definitions for system variables
#include <sys/socket.h> //definitions / structures for sockets
#include <netinet/in.h> //const's and structures used by internet domain

void error(const char *msg) //takes litteral msg passed in and prints, then exits. 
{
    perror(msg); //man perror
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd,    // socket file descriptor 1. both return values from system 
         newsockfd, // socket file descriptor 2
         portno;    // port number to associate with this socket

     socklen_t clilen; //stored address size  of each client
     char      buffer[256]; //stores chars from socket buffer
     struct    sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     /*sockaddr_in, structure containing an internet address. most of the magic DEFINED BELOW
            struct sockaddr_in
            {
                short   sin_family; /* must be AF_INET 
                 u_short sin_port;
                 struct  in_addr sin_addr;
                 char    sin_zero[8]; /* Not used, must be zero 
            };
     */
     int n; //stores return values of read() / write() system calls)

     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     } //self explanitory

     /*socket()  creates a new socket and takes 3 arguments, the first being the address domain of the socket
      *      Sockets in this case can use two types of domains which are both system constants 
      *             AF_UNIX - Used for parent child prc's on the same machine
      *             AF_INET - Used for host to host communication, Ie internet communication
      *
      *     The second option SOCKET_STREAM is the type of stream/communication used in the socket. ie TCP/UDP, Being
      *             SOCK_STREAM - TCP - A continuous stream/connection during the life span of the sockets communication
      *             SOCK_DGRAM  - UDP - A connectionless strea/connection which uses less resources/is faster but possible byte loss
      * 
      *     The third option is the protocol used, due to specifying the type of stream this is almost always left to 0
      *     Leaving the arg at 0 implies that the operating system will make the best call and due to setting the stream it will
      *     more then likely choose to use the requested method
      * 
      *     This socket() in general returns a value for the subsequent descriptor for reference. If on failure, the socket()
      *     will return -1 and fail hence if(sockfd<0){}
   * 
   *   man socket() for information Andrew,
      */
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0) 
            error("ERROR opening socket");

     /*bzero() sets all values in buffer to 0(00000000)*/
     bzero(
        (char *) &serv_addr,
         sizeof(serv_addr)
          ); //Deref &serv_addr, and ensures to 0 out all bytes in buffer(entire struct)

     portno = atoi(argv[1]);//port number to be used for communication, 

     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //set to internet. sin_family is stored in sockadr_in structure
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //structure in structure. s_addr holds the host address. IN_ADDR is always the systems ip
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno); //convert to network byte order. Holds th eport number, places into readable format
     /*
           * checks and binds to new file descripter, socketaddr(deref) and allocates the size of the address bound to. 
           * If less then zero. it will fail(-1)
         */
     if (bind(sockfd, 
             (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, 
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
            error("ERROR on binding");

     listen(sockfd,5); // listens on bound socket/descriptor and allows up to 5 connections to be waiting in queue(max allowed on system 
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr); // assigns value based on size of bytes in clients address
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, // new descripter to use when accepting a client
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, //gathers client connection information for arg(deref)
                 &clilen); // Passes in clilen, for lenght of client address. not a copy, the real shiz

     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept"); // again, don't be a fucking dick.
     bzero(buffer,256); // ensure buffer is not tampered at this point or gross

     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255); // use sys-call read() to store data in buffer from client. use 255bytes or client input
                                     // which ever is less.
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket"); // if failed as fuck, let's cry

     n = write(newsockfd,"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n",16); // Write back to client. to bound socket from client. they see this shit.
     n = write(newsockfd,"Connection: Keep-alive\n",23);
     n = write(newsockfd,"Connection: close\n",18);
     n = write(newsockfd,"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n",39);
     n = write(newsockfd,"\n",1);
     n = write(newsockfd,"<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html><head><title>Hello World!</title></head>\n",62);
     n = write(newsockfd,"<body><h1>Hello World!</h1>\n",28);
     n = write(newsockfd,"</body></html>\n",15);




     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket"); // duh

     // cleaning up...
       //close(newsockfd);
      // close(sockfd);
getchar();
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not `\n.`

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, this doesn't seem to establish a fix for the above mentioned code.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment. Did you alter the lengths when you fixed that? And did you fix it on every line? There are certainly further issues. For example you're specifying both keep-alive and close, which makes zero sense, and neither is valid in HTTP 1.0. I suggest you take a good look at the RFCs instead of just making it up.

Comment: I I actually meant to remove keep-alive. and I obtained the response codes based on website requests through inspect header information. And saw that the http server on the other end would return such information upon requests of various web pages.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of things wrong with your code. The main problem you probably have is that you are not telling the client when the end of the response body is reached, so that the client does not know that the body is done and thus will try to read more data forever and not display what it already has. The usual ways are specifying a `Content-Length`, using `chunked` transfer encoding (HTTP/1.1+ only), or closing the socket after the body is done.  See [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 "Message Length"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) for specific details.

Apart from that (some of the things are already pointed out by [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) in the comments):

- wrong line endings, e.g. LF instead of CR LF
- conflicting information in the `Connection` header
- you don't properly read the request, but just assume it will be in the first packet and no longer than 255 byte
- no proper error checking: `write()` is not guaranteed to write the whole buffer

> I obtained the response codes based on website requests through inspect header information

Please don't do an implementation by only looking at a few samples of traffic without even understanding them properly. There are already enough broken HTTP servers out there and enough clients which work around these servers and all this is causing lots of trouble. Usually these servers are also only tested against a few selected clients and then the trouble starts once this kind of servers are rolled out and then surprisingly break with other clients. Please read the actual [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and write your server to conform to it.

Comment: I actually do not plan to use this in production by any means. THis is simply something to learn more about sockets.

Comment: @andrew Intended usage doesn't alter required compliance. You asked why it doesn't work. This is why it doesn't work. You can't implement network protocols by guesswork. If you don't care whether it works why ask the question?

Comment: If you just want to learn about sockets, implementing HTTP was not the best choice for that.  HTTP is a complex protocol to implement from scratch.  You should have started with something simpler, like [ECHO](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc862).

Comment: I understand that. But this is something I decided to practice on my own from just getting into sockets. Regardless though, would you happen to know why this does not work on windows? I am least getting somewhere with linux

Comment: By not working on windows. I simply mean that as the server is running it does not dispaly in a windows web browser as it does on linux.

Comment: If client and server are on the same system (i.e. communicate over loopback) the behavior is different than to the case of different system. Also, different browsers behave differently when confronted with bad or incomplete (like in this case) data and even same browsers can behave differently if the underlying network stack is different.